# 2px difference `outerHeight()` between Chrome and every other browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on this custom select menu that is part of a forms plugin I'm developing.

In my css I've something like this:

```
.qval-select span {
    font-size: 15px;
    display: block;
    padding: .3em .8em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

The `span` is an item from the custom select menu.

At some point I need to know the item's `outerHeight()` and do some calculations. The problem I'm having is that Chrome reports a height of `25px` and every other browser (IE8, IE9, Firefox) reports `27px`. The funny part is that only Chrome seems to be getting the number I'm looking for.

To see what I mean, I uploaded an example here:

http://spacirdesigns.com/idealforms/.

The problem is evident when you open the custom select menu and scroll with the up and down arrows. As you can see, every browser except Chrome will count 2 extra pixel and screw up the whole thing.
If you open the console you can see the log of the height and compare to other browsers.

If I set a height in `px` for the `span` everything works fine, but the beauty of having a custom select is to be able adapt it to many sizes so I need `em`. I also tried setting the font in `em` and changing the font as well, but nothing.

Can somebody tell me what's happening here and why? It's driving me nuts.

```
scrollToItem: function() {
    // Select.sub.scrollTop(0);
    var idx = Select.items.find('.selected').parent().index(),
        height = Select.items.outerHeight(),
        items = Select.items.length,
        allHeight = height * items,
        curHeight = height * (items - idx);
    console.log(height);
    Select.sub.scrollTop(allHeight - curHeight);
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because EM is based on the browser. There's no way around this, except to account for the changes somehow.

Chrome says .3 EM = 5px, other browsers say 6px. It's your padding that's making the height larger, and as your padding is in EM, you end up with different heights.

Comment: Yeah, it has to be something like this. But why Chrome ONLY reports 25px and all others 27? Chrome is the only one giving me the value I want. Any other way around this without setting it in px?

Comment: Yes. You have to code in such a way that accounts for any size. Try zooming in, in Chrome, and EM should change (might not, but still). EM is browser-specific and can be different, so just take what it gives you. What are you doing with the value once you have it?

Comment: Done! It works now. I used `line-height` plus `height` Thanks.